# Capturing wireless packets on my wireless network

Tags: wifi, packet-sniffer

Is it possible to capture wireless packets on my wireless network using sniffers (ie. wireshark)? If so, could you give links that can guide me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes very much possible. You already named the best in the class.

[Sniff Wireless Packets with Wireshark in windows](http://www.wireless-nets.com/resources/tutorials/sniff_packets_wireshark.html)

Comment: I am assuming Dave is using windows.

Comment: I am using Windows. :)

Answer (score -1):

airdump-ng is great if you want to capture packets and save them for later usage.

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng